# What are the names of the voice actors of the video game "Cyberswine?"

Tags: video-games, behind-the-scenes, actors

I have seen [playthroughs](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=NCLTm0fGzDc) of the Cyberswine game on YouTube but there are no credits for the voice actors, which I think is really unfair to the voice talent involved.

The only voice actor who has (partically) confirmed his involvement in the game is Quinton Flynn who was the voice of the boy Zak. He revealed this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/quintonflynn/status/911845718285004802?lang=en)

**Who voiced the other characters?**

Comment: [IMDB page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt22088550/fullcredits/) also lists no voice credits (currently)

Answer (score 6):

I was wondering if they used the same voice artists as for some of their other games - the credits to their Xena Multipath Movies are [on youtube](https://youtu.be/Z685EtFhoFE&t=180); that game has the same sound editors as Cyberswine (Gregory Hodge and Peter O'Brien) so it would make sense if they reused voice actors (the ones credited on Xena are Heidi Anderson, Susan Davis, Scott McDonald, Jasmin Paul, Nicholas Omana and Lou Wagner). Sure enough, googling for Nicholas Omana confirms that he was also in Cyberswine, according to [this talent management website](http://www.novatmc.com/Voice-Over-Talent/voice-over-management/voice-over-talent/male-talent/nick-omana/):

> Nick has created hundreds of character voices for Disney, Hanna-Barbera, Marikami/Wolf, and Warner Brothers, plus voiced characters for game projects such as James Bond: Golden Eye 2, Enter the Matrix, X-Men, Cyberswine, XComm, Xena: Warrior Princess, Gravity Angels, and Popeye.

That's one of the actors, anyway! Unsure which character he voiced.